# Why are constructions such as ‘AN historian’ commonly pronounced with a non-silent H?

Tags: english, grammar, pronunciation, articulation, conjunctions

It is well-known that the determiner *a* is substituted with *an* when the following word begins with a vowel (letter or sound). In some cases, however, *an* has been used preceding words beginning with (as spoken) [h].

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/historic#Usage_notes), “like many terms that start with a non-silent *h* but have emphasis on their second syllable, some people precede *historical* with *an*, others with *a*.”

If syllabic emphasis is one explanation, how is this distinction acquired? What makes it significant enough to influence a person’s speech/writing?

My theory is that phrases such as *an historian*, in which the *H* is commonly pronounced, originated as a hypercorrection since propagated by a small number of native English speakers.

Comment: I don’t understand what your question really is here. The distinction is acquired the same way the rest of the language is acquired, just like any other phonemically based distinction…

Comment: Except very few people use it, and those people don’t seem to be concerned they may be wrong. @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: Why should they be? It’s become less common now, but it used to be very common; are you concerned you’re ‘wrong’ about any of the not-so-common features you have in your speech?

Comment: If I have any ‘unusual’ pronunciations, it’s probably intentional on my part. Anyway, do you have any further information on how common sounding the H in this scenario used to be?  @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: Unfortunately not, no; it’s just the sort of thing that I remember older people always doing and younger people not doing when I was a kid. I think of it as similar to the past subjunctive in BrE – a case where I’m unusual, since I use it naturally, even though hardly anyone else does anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I suppose I use the past subjunctive fairly often myself. One thing I’ve started doing since becoming interested in linguistics is sounding the initial ‘c’ in words like ‘electric’. I can’t help it now that I realise I wasn’t doing it before, ha ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial syllable of words like "historical" which take "an" can often drop the h (in pronunciation, not in writing).  After dropping the h, of course, they start with a vowel and now satisfy the condition for using "an" rather than "a". So apparently we need to revise the condition for using "an": Use "an" before a word either starting with a vowel or one which *could* start with a vowel.

Comment: While I agree, the phrase ‘an historian’ (as I’ve heard it) is accompanied by a spoken ‘H’.

Comment: @MadBanners  Yes, for me, too.  That's why I said "*could*" start with a vowel.  It doesn't necessarily *actually* start with a vowel.

Comment: Ah, so you’re saying the sound before the vowel could be considered ‘invisible’ — especially when it’s part of the first syllable. That makes a lot of sense, while only a limited number of synergies would sound natural.

Comment: @MadBanners, That's not exactly what I intend.  I am saying that you get "an" when the next word could, in some styles and some dialects, start with a vowel.  One can imagine that, once upon a time, "an" became popular here in some prestige dialect which did consistently drop the h here, and we all emulated that usage of "an".  It became a convention.